# How to write mobile number length validation in magento by prototype

Tags: magento-1.8, validation, form-validation

I want to create mobile number validation in magento.
Number should to be not less then 10 (7428832128)....
i need to write this by prototype...
basically i don't know how to write this....

Answer (score 11):

By Default Magento give number of validation classes.you just need to use the class name.Its easy find the html tag where their is mobile number html and add a class attribute to that input type and under the class add the following classes `"validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits"`

Like in my case it was

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" title="Mobile" class="input-text required-entry validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits">
```

For more reference of classes [More Validation Classes](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Comment: ..its working but i need proper message'mobile number is not valid'

Comment: go to js/prototype and open validation.js and find the Text length does not satisfy specified text range. replace this text with what u want.then u have done.

Comment: Refresh Cache and check now

Comment: if this is solves your problem please accept this answer and upvote also

Comment: do you have any idea abot this... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49808/magento-product-with-no-image-filter-issue-on-seraching-bt-working-fine-on-categ/49809#49809

Comment: max length is working .. but minimum length is not working.. any idea..?