# Validation for Zip code with only 6 numbers & Digits in view page

Tags: configurable-product, shipping, discount

in Product view page we are displaying textfield to

enter zip code and find shipping is available or not .

We want to validate with only numbers & 6 digits.

if we enter other than above condition, it should give error as Invalid Zip code.

[image]

```
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 

<label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label> 
<div class="search"> 

<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" /> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer for the your question

**Source :**[How to write mobile number length validation in magento by prototype](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49794/how-to-write-mobile-number-length-validation-in-magento-by-prototype)

By Default Magento give number of validation classes.you just need to use the class name.Its easy find the html tag where their is mobile number html and add a class attribute to that input type and under the class add the following classes `"validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits"`

Like in my case it was

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" title="Mobile" class="input-text required-entry validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits">
```

For more reference of classes [More Validation Classes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49794/how-to-write-mobile-number-length-validation-in-magento-by-prototype)

You should update the input class like this:

```
<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
required-entry<?php endif;?> validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its working please check, i want to change error message :  http://prntscr.com/alwbw3

Comment: @BabyinMagento use this [solution](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Comment: Fantastic, seems you know entire magento links in google : -) Thanks a lot for support.